# Java: encrypted server/clients bi-directional communication?

Tags: java, sockets, netty, bidirectional

What is the best way to establish an encrypted bi-directional communication between a server and multiple clients?

The server has persistence database, and will send data to clients and clients will send back data. This must be encrypted for best protection against network sniffing tools and etc.

Would Netty server be a good candidate for this? Can I use sockets with netty and client applications to connect to the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just encrypt the socket and send whatever protocol you like over the wire. HTTPS is just one of them. For example we have implemented SMTPS on top of netty without any problems.

You just need to define the protocol, write the encoder / decoder and add them with the SslHandler in the pipeline. Thats it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that communication protocol is HTTP and you are using standard HTTP environment (HTTP server, Servlets, JSPs etc) use HTTPS communication. It guarantees encryption and protection of your data in both directions.

Comment: what other non http solution exists? I ask this because I read that to get https certificate is super expensive.

Comment: You don't need to use a Certification Authority in order to use SSL. If you bundle the server's public key within your client, CA are not needed ... which means that you don't have to pay anything.

Comment: It is a lightyear faster and easier and safer to use HTTPS than roll your own in-house encription, or use the Java encryption API on your own. You can issue your own keys, and even purchasing an SSL certificate does not cost *that* much, google for it. Voting up this answer.